# Algebraic Topology problem on continuous functions over disks on sphere

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have come across the next problem, and I would like a little hint. Everything I'm thinking is not working or is a dead end.

Let $f,g : D^2 \rightarrow S^2$ be continous maps such that $(x,y) \in S^1$ implies $f(x,y) = (x,y,0)$ and $g(x,y) = (-y,x,0)$. Prove that there must exist $(x,y) \in D^2$ such that $f(x,y) = \pm g(x,y)$.

Any hint towards the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try composing $f$ and $g$ with the quotient map from $S^2$ into the real projective plane ${\mathbf P}^2(\mathbf R)$?

Comment: I will try to go that way. Thanks

Comment: I couldn't get to anything

Comment: Could you help me out?

Comment: Let $p$ be the quotient map from $S^2$ to $\mathbf P^2(\mathbf R)$. Consider $p\circ f$ and $p\circ g$ as morphisms of pairs from $(D^2,S^1)$ to $(\mathbf P^2(\mathbf R),\mathbf P^1(\mathbf R))$. They induce morphisms of quotients $\bar f$ and $\bar g$ from $D^2/S^1$ to $\mathbf P^2(\mathbf R)/\mathbf P^1(\mathbf R)$...

Comment: Then I would just have two continuous functions from $S^2 \rightarrow S^2$

Comment: How would you prove those induced morphisms must have a same image for some point

Comment: The general approach in showing that two continuous maps $f,g\colon X\rightarrow Y$ have $f(x)=g(x)$ for some $x\in X$ is to consider the map $(f,g)\colon X\rightarrow Y\times Y$ and show that its image intersects the diagonal $\Delta\subseteq Y\times Y$...